# Android: RIL porting - Issue with network settings using my GPRS+GSM (pppd+chat)

Tags: android, pppd

Android porting on ARM based EVK system integrated with GPRS+GSM (UART) based module is up.
Able to port RIL layer as well and make calls and SMS using my network provider SIM.

However when i choose (settings->Wireless Networks->Mobile Networks-> APN or search mobile networks) i fail to get any APN settings.

To be specific, i am unable to get localip, remoteip and get my network up on my customized Android Device. Have compiled pppd and chat for Android as well and have made appropriate script files to run pppd and chat, still i get Configuration script file error.

Would appreciate if i can get some tips on approaching the right direction to get the network up using my GPRS+GSM module.

Thx in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've been porting ril on pandaboard with an expansion board. I also failed to get any APN settings during the runtime. But I can set the APN before building the AOSP. The apn information is recorded in a xml file called **apns-conf.xml** located at *android/development/data/etc*. You can config the apn in this file!

For example,

```
<apn carrier="Android"
     mcc="310"
     mnc="995"
     apn="internet"
     user="*"
     server="*"
     password="*"
     mmsc="null"
/>
```

Besides, you have to ensure that this "apns-conf.xml" is correctly install.
In *build/core/main.mk*, you can check it.

For example,

```
ifeq (,$(filter %:system/etc/apns-conf.xml, $(PRODUCT_COPY_FILES)))
    PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    development/data/etc/apns-conf_sdk.xml:system/etc/apns-conf.xml
    ifeq ($(filter eng tests,$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)),)
        $(warning implicitly installing apns-conf_sdk.xml)
    endif
endif
```

Finally, you can debug your system by adb shell

```
logcat
```

and

```
logcat -b radio
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done the opposite of what you have done. I did not care about the SMS and voice, I just needed the data connection. Right after you boot, run "logcat -b radio -v time" from ADB. This is the radio log. You should see any attempt and result on setting up a data connection. In the log, you should see a "trySetupData".  This is the beginning of the process of establishing an IP link over the GSM link. If you read the logs carefully, you will see all the progress/status and errors. That should give you some hints on what to do next. That is how I made mine work.